# Maven Failed to Execute Goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin2.22.2 And maven-compiler

Tags: maven

I get some errors when I try to run the maven test in Intellij. When I try to run the test from maven I get the following maven-sunfire error :
**"Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin".** I updated my pom.xml file to different maven-sunfire-plugin versions...

Also when I use the following command : **mvn clean install -U** , I also get an error.

**"[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on proje
ct AnimalShelter: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --module-path -> [Help 1]"**

I just want to run the test via maven, I tried so many things but maven just won't work. My test are fine, I tested them solo and together via "Run all tests". Just in Maven it won't work.

I searched alot and also tried to **delete the .m2 file**. Also not working.

I use java version 12

my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.julianlu</groupId>
    <artifactId>AnimalShelter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My module-info.java

```java
module AnimalShelter {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens ui;
    exports ui;
    exports classes;
    exports Interfaces;
}
```

Comment: first add complete pom file furthermore have you added a module-info file in your project? Are you running on plain command line? Which Java version do you use? Please all logging output ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I added some more information. Yes I do have a module-info file

Comment: First If you like to use JDK 12 your JAVA_HOME needs to be correct which obviously is not cause the error message shows it...furthermore if you like to use junit jupiter for your tests you have to use junit-jupiter-engine as a dependency and I recommend to use most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: @khmarbaise It is the most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin. Now I changed it to JDK 12, How do i set the JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Are you running on plain command line? which operation system?

Comment: Windows 10, yes I use the terminal in Intellij

Comment: @khmarbaise Forgot to tag

Comment: so you have to set environment variable within in Windows and restart IDEA ...